# switching from user to root and revers (FreeBSD)

Tags: software-installation, sudo, freebsd, users, root

I want to make some modification with root and then with my user, in fact I want to install sudo and he give me the error in the first step:

```
cd /usr/ports/security/sudo
make install clean
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/821/errorunix.png/

I was trying to log in with root in another session `Alt+F2` but after entry the login and the password the system keep going to ask me to put again the user and the password .. so what is wrong??

I searched in the FreeBSD handbook http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ but nothing!! how this is possible??

Later EDIT: apologize., that in fact here is 2 questions., one about how to switch from user to root and then from root to user and the problem with sudo, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `su`, to gain a root shell as a user, enter *root*'s password when asked.  See `man su` for more info:

> NAME
>        `su` — substitute user identity
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        `su [-] [-flms] [-c class] [login [args]]`
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The `su` utility requests appropriate user credentials via PAM and switches
>        to that user ID (the default user is the superuser).  A shell is then
>        executed.

It also lets you switch from root to user, just use `su - loginname`

The ports error you posted comes from running `make install` as a non-root user, so using `su` first, everything should be fine.  Be aware that you can also grab a binary packages via `pkg_add -r sudo` (as root).

**Edit** I just had a closer look, could it be that your root account's shell is set to `/usr/local/bin/bash` but that this file does not exist?  If so, [check this forum thread on how to resolve the "root shell messed up" issue](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=5332), and give this a try:

```
 $ su -m root -c /bin/csh
 Password:  # <-- root password
 # chsh     # <-- change root shell
```

(But also read the hints on using the `toor` user as a better admin account while leaving `root` safe and intact.)

Comment: is a very good answer sr_., but unfortunately i try su and then i put the password, i have the same pass to my 2 users - root and pstnc (pstnc is a user that i created manually) and give me the error: BAD SU pstnc to root, see the screenshot please., and thank you .. best regards

Comment: the screenshot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/errunix2.png/

Comment: Please see my edit `:)`

Comment: hi again, i try it and is still not working .. i try the 3 solutions, 2 from the forum topic and yours, but unsuccessfully :( i attach the screenshot with my tests http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/errorunix3.png/ .. Question: i dont now if have something to do with that yesterday i create 2 new sessions Alt+F2, Alt+F3 and for that reason is not working!?! just asking

Comment: Really try [this](http://forums.freebsd.org/showpost.php?p=31583&postcount=5), i.e. *boot in single user mode* etc., **but** change the root shell (`chsh root`) to `/bin/csh`, **not** `/usr/local/bin/bash` (since it doesn't exist).

Comment: ohh i'm so sorry sr_ you came like a good man to solve a problem, but little by little i put you in a lot of problems of a strange situation that i have., right now is impossible to boot my virtual machine i attach the screenshot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/thisgotofar.png/

Comment: I don't know how to use VMWare player, can't you just *kill it*?  Using the virtual equivalent of pulling the plug?  (if there's nothing unsaved to lose.)

Comment: i try it in another pc and is work perfectly., for the rest of the problems i start a new topic, because something is wrong with what i have in my laptop.. thank you